# Why can't the Ubuntu installer simply preinstall the latest Nvidia driver?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

Why can't the Ubuntu installer simply pre-install the latest Nvidia driver and the CUDA drivers? I am tired of trying again and again and just getting errors. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why Ubuntu does not include the proprietary NVIDIA drivers and CUDA programs by default is that these packages have a history of causing black screen problems on some computers, and the built-in open source nouveau driver does not have this problem. So a black screen problem caused by a proprietary graphics driver can almost always be solved by uninstalling the driver from a text-only console and rebooting the computer. When the computer reboots it will be using the default open source graphics driver, and you will have an opportunity to calmly consider what to do next about installing a better driver for your NVIDIA graphics processor.

Answer (score 0):

It is all copyright matters.Some software is not open source and eligible for personal use only.That's way they cannot be included.